# Look through Apache Requests

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, load-balancing, test, request

is there any way to grab REQUEST variables as well as other apache information for each request processed? This would especially be handy through a load balancer and proxy as well in order to track each step of the process to an end web server.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the apache log file as it grows at real time by executing the following command

```
tail -f /var/log/httpd/access.log
```

This shows all the lines being appended to log file at that particular time.

or follow the link

http://atoztechnical.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-to-view-log-file-as-it-grows-at.html

Answer (score 0):

Adjusts the verbosity of the messages -[Apache doc -LogLevel](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#loglevel).
You can do it in global config in httpd.conf. 
Or per VHost inside of VirtualHost directive (this way you will be able to configure additional log files using ErrorLog and TransferLog directives).

If you like, you can modify log format, like shown [here](http://www.webreference.com/internet/logs/). By using %r you are able to
get the text of the original request line along with HTTP method used.

Then restart/reload apache and try:

tail -f /var/log/httpd/logfile